# Unable to reach cloud run services externally after successful deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

This is my first time using Cloud Run -fully managed on my GCP project. I have successfully deployed my services to Cloud Run using Cloud Build. I set up a cloudbuild.yaml file that builds my container from the repo, pushes to Container Registry, and deploys to cloud run. 
The build executes successfully and I can see my services running in the cloud run dashboard. However, when I make a call to the provided URL it returns no response.

- The browser says "server IP address could not be found."
- Postman returns "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" Status Code 443.
- Pinging the provided URL returns "Unknown Host"
- The containers run locally and work as expected

To be sure the problem isn't coming from my code or container, I deployed this demo service [laravel6-on-google-cloud-run](https://github.com/geshan/laravel6-on-google-cloud-run) but I got the same result.

I noticed that when I curl the service endpoint from Cloud Shell (making the request from within google's internal network). It works as expected. So maybe it is a firewall thing. Does my VPC firewall settings affect Cloud Run services as well? 
I configured the services to allow Unauthenticated access. Connectivity is set to external.

 
**Update**:
I noticed that the services are working on other devices, just not my laptop. I'm not sure why yet, but it's safe to say that this is a local issue and not a Cloud Run problem.

Comment: Did you try with another device? Like your cell phone? Do you have special error logs into Cloud Run logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You're right! It's working on my phone. Do you have any idea why it's working on other devices but not my laptop?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with your laptop. Do you have software proxy or firewall that intercept/change the TCP traffic?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I don't believe I have any firewall or proxy setup, but I'm investigating. At least I can say for sure that this is definitely not a Cloud Run issue, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Most likely you have a DNS server issue. Check your laptop's network configuration and determine which DNS servers are configured. I usually change these settings from my ISP's DNS servers to Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: @JohnHanley I've configured my DNS to use Google's domains. Still no luck. Strange indeed.

Comment: @David how did you solve it? I have the exact same issue. I thought it was a DNS propagation issue, so I waited (2 days), but still it doesn't work. I deployed the service again, but still no luck... I have tried using my ISP DNS, Cloudflare DNS, Google DNS, but it doesn't work. It works from my phone though...

Comment: @csalazar It turned out I had registered another app to use the .app domain locally. Laravel Homestead to be specific. Cloud run instances all end in .app So the urls were resolving locally instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that cloud run instance urls are on the .app domain.

I had previously installed an application that had registered to use the .app domain locally. So calls to urls with that domain got resolved locally instead.

To confirm that you are having this issue perform an nslookup on your cloud run url.

```
$ nslookup <cloudrun-service-url>.com
```

If this resolves then you are likely facing this issue. Removing this entry from '/etc/resolver/' should help solve this issue